# The codegolf object

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

Imagine this, we have an environment with a global scope containing just a single object, called `codegolf`. This object has a single child called `stackexchange`, which has a property called `com`.
Accessing this property would look like `codegolf.stackexchange.com`.

#### The challenge

The input of your program/function will be a string trying to access a property on the global scope. Whenever this property is found, you shall print/return a truthy value. If the property isn't found, a falsy value shall be printed/returned. The catch: when you try to access a property on a non-existant object, your program should throw any kind of error¹.

To make things a bit easier, you may assume that input will always be `[a-z.]`, it will never be empty, it will never have repeating `.`'s and it will never start or end with a `.`. So `codegolf.` is an invalid input.

#### Test cases

```
codegolf.stackexchange.com => 1 // or any other truthy value
codegolf.stackexchange.net => 0 // or any other falsy value
codegolf.stackexchange => 1
codegolf.foo => 0
codegolf => 1
foo => 0
codegolf.com => 0
codegolf.constructor => 0

codegolf.foo.bar => Error (since foo is undefined)
codegolf.stackexchange.com.foo => Error (since com is a value, not an object)
codegolf.stackexchange.com.foo.bar => Error
foo.stackexchange.com => Error
foo.bar => Error
foo.bar.baz => Error
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins

¹ if (and only if) your language of choice doesn't support errors **at all**, you must output something which makes it clear that this is an error. For example, if you use 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy, you may use "e" for an error. Be consistent in your return values and explain the behaviour in your post.

Comment: I feel like `foo => Error` would be more appropriate.

Comment: request to add `codegolf.com` to the test cases to rule out `codegolf(.stackexchange)?(.com)?$` type checks

Comment: Another missing test case: `foo.stackexchange.com`

Comment: @carusocomputing Nope. Think about JavaScript. `foo` would return `undefined`, but it wouldn't throw an error. `foo.bar` would throw an error because `foo` is not defined.

Comment: @mbomb007 I mean, for Javascript yeah, for many other languages, that's not the case.

Comment: @carusocomputing True, but you can't say it's "more appropriate", when it makes sense both ways. `codegolf.foo => 0`, so `foo => 0`.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript, 135 bytes

```
v=>(c=(p,i)=>new Proxy({}, {get:(o,q)=>(r=q==p[i]?c(p,i+1):o.$,i==3?r||z:r)}),x=c(["codegolf","stackexchange","com"],0),!!eval("x."+v))
```

Reworked the first attempt to prevent builtin keys being accessible, at this point its going to be better to use a different approach, but hey!

Returns true for valid, false for missing and errors on error.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

Returns `false`/ `true` or throws `ReferenceError`.

```js
s=>s.split`.`.map((w,i)=>e|['codegolf','stackexchange','com'][i]!=w&&e++,e=0)&&e>1?X:!e
```

```js
let f =
    
s=>s.split`.`.map((w,i)=>e|['codegolf','stackexchange','com'][i]!=w&&e++,e=0)&&e>1?X:!e

console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange.com')); // => true
console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange.net')); // => false
console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange'));     // => true
console.log(f('codegolf.foo'));               // => false
console.log(f('codegolf'));                   // => true
console.log(f('foo'));                        // => false
console.log(f('codegolf.com'));               // => false

console.log(f('codegolf.foo.bar'));           // => Error
```

#### Probabilistic version, 78 bytes (non-competing)

Because all properties are guaranteed to match `[a-z]`, we can give this a try:

```js
s=>s.split`.`.map((w,i)=>e|[162,6,2][i]-parseInt(w,36)%587&&e++,e=0)&&e>1?X:!e
```

Apart from the fact that `587` is a prime and leads to rather short values for the words we are interested in, this is a rather random modulo choice.

Although it does pass all test cases, it is of course likely to return false-positives.

```js
let f =
    
s=>s.split`.`.map((w,i)=>e|[162,6,2][i]-parseInt(w,36)%587&&e++,e=0)&&e>1?X:!e

console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange.com')); // => true
console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange.net')); // => false
console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange'));     // => true
console.log(f('codegolf.foo'));               // => false
console.log(f('codegolf'));                   // => true
console.log(f('foo'));                        // => false
console.log(f('codegolf.com'));               // => false

console.log(f('codegolf.foo.bar'));           // => Error
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, <s>269</s> 231 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ps=
set w=1codegolf
for %%a in (%s:.= %)do call:l %%w
echo %w:~0,1%
exit/b
:g
if
:l
if %w:~-1%==. goto g
if not %1==%w% set w=0.&exit/b
set w=1com
if %1==com set w=1.
if %1==codegolf set w=1stackexchange
```

Takes input on STDIN; throws a syntax error for an invalid property. Works by using `w` as a state machine. If `w` ends with a `.` this means that the next property access is invalid. Edit: Saved 17 bytes by using the syntax error to abort the batch script. Saved 21 bytes by realising that one of my assignments could be unconditional.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>84</s> 82 bytes

Not short enough to win, but since I am a beginner I thought it would be fun to share it. Maybe someone has a suggestion for improvement.

```
s=>s.split`.`.length>3&&e||!!eval('codegolf={stackexchange:{com:true}};window.'+s)
```

It passes all the tests in the question, returns `true` for existing value, `false` for non-existent and it throws an error if you try to get a property of a non-existent or non-object variable. However I now realize that this solution has some issues as well. As pointed out by @Florent in the comments it returns true when string prototype properties such as `.toString` are called.

**Edit**: 2 bytes shorter thanks to @MamaFunRoll

Test snippet:

```js
var f =
s=>s.split`.`.length>3&&e||!!eval('codegolf={stackexchange:{com:true}};window.'+s)

console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange.com')) //true
console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange.net')) //false
console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange')) //true
console.log(f('codegolf.foo')) //false
console.log(f('codegolf')) //true
console.log(f('foo')) //false
console.log(f('codegolf.com')) //false

console.log(f('codegolf.foo.bar')) // TypeError
console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange.com.foo')) //ReferenceError
console.log(f('codegolf.stackexchange.com.foo.bar')) //ReferenceError
console.log(f('foo.stackexchange.com')) // TypeError
console.log(f('foo.bar')) // TypeError
console.log(f('foo.bar.baz')) // TypeError
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Unable to get property 'bar' of undefined or null reference",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1,
  "colno": 37
}

Comment: @RosLuP I am not sure what you mean by this comment. The function is supposed to throw an error for `codegolf.foo.bar`

Comment: than all ok for all you... but for me "throw" error is one error

Comment: @RosLuP yes, that's because all JavaScript scripts stops on the first error

Comment: `.split('.')` -> `split\`.\`` Welcome!

Comment: Does not work. `f("codegolf.toString")`  should return `false`. `f("codegolf.toString.toString")` should throw.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>98</strike> <s>112</s> 113 bytes

```
f(char*a){char*c="codegolf.stackexchage.com";while(*c&&*c==*a)++a,++c;return strchr(a,46)?*(a=0):!(*a|*c&*c-46);}
```

ungolfed

```
f(char*a){char*c="codegolf.stackexchage.com";
          while(*c&&*c==*a)++a,++c;
          return strchr(a,46)?*(a=0):!(*a|*c&*c-46);
         }

f(codegolf.stackexchage.com)=1
f(codegolf.stackexchage.net)=0
f(codegolf.stackexchage)=1
f(codegolf.foo)=0
f(codegolf)=1
f(foo)=0
```

for the below it has to seg fault

```
f(codegolf.stackexchage.com.foo)
f(foo.bar)
f(foo.bar.baz)
f(codegolf.foo.bar)
f(foo.v)
```

Comment: What about the error(s)? `f(codegolf.stackexchage.com.foo)` should error, not return `0`, for example.

Comment: i don't fully understand why my C language entry that is less characters than 
C#,Java,Javascript, python,Bathc,Javascript, has less points (-1) than everyone

Comment: Maybe they downvoted before you fixed the codegolf.stackexchange.com.foo error, or they don't realize you fixed it.  Edit the header to `# C, <strike>98</strike> 112 bytes #` to make it clear that you modified it.

Comment: `3` is not an error either, in C it is what is considered a "truthy" value. See [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/53748), and [this code](http://ideone.com/miJEdk).

Comment: I not use exceptions, in case of error program return 3. Should be -1 but 3 save 1 character

Comment: @Ray thank you. In C the prefered way it is not exception, as in the not good languages, but it return one error code to the caller (as it has to be)

Comment: If people *insist* on a fatal exception, you could return `1/0` instead of `3` to raise a floating point exception signal.  But in a real program, returning a separate error code for separate types of errors, as you do here, is the Right Thing to do in C.  And since raising SIGFPE is mandated by the OS and hardware, not the language, it's my opinion that what you do here is both within the letter and spirit of the problem description.

Comment: 1/0 return 1, \*0 is not allowed... 1/0.0 not seg fault. What seg fault is \*(a=0) or \*(char\*)0

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 173 bytes

```
function d(a){var b="codegolf",u="stackexchange",c=a.split("."),e="e";return c.length==1?c[0]==b:c.length==2?c[0]==b?c[1]==u:e:c.length==3?c[0]==b?c[1]==u?c[2]=="com":e:e:e}
```

Works with IE 10, so should work on major modern browsers.

**[Try it here (+ ungolfed)](https://repl.it/Ebkr/1)**

Comment: Could be way more golfed: `d=(a,b="codegolf",u="stackexchange",c=a.split\`.\`,e="e")=>c[l="length"]==1?c[0]==b:c[l]==2?c[0]==b?c[1]==u:e:c[l]==3?c[0]==b?c[1]==u?c[2]=="com":e:e:e` (149 bytes)

Comment: @Florent I think he's trying to allow it to work on IE10 etc., so no arrow functions or default parameters.

Comment: +1 for a great answer, +1 for `e="e"`, but -1 for IE 10.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 155 bytes

Wasn't going to be the shortest but thought it would be fun give it a go in C#...

```
bool f(string s){var a=s.Split('.');int e=0,l=a.Length-1,i=l;for(;0<=i;i--){e+=a[i]!=new[]{"codegolf","stackexchange","com"}[i]?i<l?s[-1]:1:0;}return e<1;}
```

- Splits the string and reverse iterates through the result.
- A non matching element more than 1 iteration deep, errors (throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException` by accessing a char at -1 position in the string).
- Otherwise, returns false if any elements didn't match.

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Na727)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>84</s> 80 bytes

Anonymous function which returns `true` or `false`, or divides by zero to raise error:

```rb
->s{k=1;s.split(?.).zip(%w[codegolf stackexchange com]){|i,o|1/0if !k;k=i==o};k}
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/Ebus/1)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>187</s> 138 bytes

Version 2.0(**138** bytes):
Idea shamelessly stolen from @Jamie.

```
l->{for(String []a=l.split,int l=i=a.length-1,e=0;i>=0;e+=a[i]!=new String[]{"codegolf","stackexchange","com"}[i]?i<l?s[-1]:1:0)return e;}
```

Version 1.0(**187** bytes):

```
l->{String[]a=l.split(".");return a[0].equals("codegolf")?(a.length<2?1:(a[1].equals("stackexchange")?(a.length<3?1:(a[2].equals("com")?1:0)):(a.length<3?0:a[-1]))):(a.length<2?0:a[-1]);}
```

Explanation of the return part:

```
return a[0].equals("codegolf")?(a.length<2?1:(a[1].equals("stackexchange")?(a.length<3?1:(a[2].equals("com")?1:0)):(a.length<3?0:a[-1]))):(a.length<2?0:a[-1]);
return                                                                                                                                                        ;
       a[0].equals("codegolf")?                                                                                                          :
                               (a.length<2? :                                                                                           ) (a.length<2? :     )
                                           1 (a[1].equals("stackexchange")?                                       :                    )              0 a[-1]
                                                                           (a.length<3? :                        ) (a.length<3? :     )
                                                                                       1 (a[2].equals("com")? : )              0 a[-1]
                                                                                                             1 0
```